# BSD memcmp(3) difference between manual and implementation

Tags: c, macos, darwin

According to `man memcmp` on OSX Darwin:

> The memcmp() function returns zero if the two strings are identical, otherwise
>        returns the difference between the first two differing bytes (treated as unsigned
>        char values, so that `\200` is greater than `\0`, for example).  Zero-length strings
>        are always identical.  This behavior is not required by C and portable code should
>        only depend on the sign of the returned value.

However, when I test this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%i\n", memcmp("\200", "\0", 1));
    return (0);
}
```

It displays `-1`, which would indicate that `\200` is less than `\0`.

Is there any explanation for this?

The compiler version according to `gcc --version` is "Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)" and the system is running High Sierra 10.13.4

Comment: The manual is wrong, it's describing `strcmp()`, not `memcmp()`.

Comment: The code might invoke undefined behaviour as the prototype for `memcmp()` might be missing.

Comment: @Barmar This makes sense, as running the same test on strncmp() returns `128`

Comment: You need to include `<string.h>` to get `memcmp()`'s prototype.

Comment: Possible but for me unverifiable answer: Darwin derives in part from FreeBSD, FreeBSD used to have a bug in its `memcmp` implementation (https://blog.bramp.net/post/2009/08/10/memcmp-broken-in-the-freebsd-kernel/), and although FreeBSD has since fixed that bug, Darwin never copied that fix. If someone can verify that this is the problem, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar @alk according to the man, it resides in `libc`. However, I have retested with only <string.h>, with the same results.

Comment: @hvd testing with `bcmp()` returns the expected `128`, so it doesn't appear to be the same bug.

Comment: The specification of memcmp return value in the ISO C standard is not very precise

Comment: Which version of OSX, which compiler version, what specific compile command?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I updated the question to reflect the versions

Comment: Possible workaround: `#include <string.h>` followed by `#undefine memcmp` ought to, by standard, remove any macro hiding the function name `memcmp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a compiler bug. The compiler incorrectly evaluates calls to `memcmp` when both arguments are literals. When `memcmp` is actually called, it returns the expected result.

The following was tested with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1) on macOS 10.13.4 (17E199). I compiled with “clang -std=c11”, with either “-O0” or “-O3” to select the optimization level, and with “-S” to generate assembly.

Consider four alternative calls to `memcmp`:

```
    printf("%i\n", memcmp("\200", "\0", 1));

    printf("%i\n", memcmp((char[] ) { '\200' }, "\0", 1));

    printf("%i\n", memcmp((unsigned char[] ) { '\200' }, "\0", 1));

    char a[1] = { 128 };
    char b[1] = { 0 };
    printf("%i\n", memcmp(a, b, 1));
```

For the first two calls, the compiler generates **incorrect** assembly that passes a hardcoded value of −1 to `printf`. There is no call to `memcmp`; it has been optimized away, even in the “-O0” version. (In the “-O0” versions, the −1 is encoded as 4294967295, which is equivalent in its context.) When `memcmp` is called with string literals or compound literals, its return value is known at compile time, so the compiler has evaluated it. However, it has done so incorrectly.

For the third call, the compiler generates **incorrect** assembly that passes a hardcoded value of 1. This suggests the compiler is (incorrectly) using the type of the literal in its evaluation.

For the fourth call, in which we use defined objects that are not literals, the “-O0” version calls `memcmp`. When run, the program prints the **correct** result, 128. For the “-O3” version, the compiler generates **correct** assembly with a hardcoded value of 128. So the compiler **does** have an algorithm that correctly evaluates a `memcmp` at compile time, but it used a different, faulty algorithm for the cases with the literals.

When one literal and one non-literal are used, the compiler generates correct code. This explains why this bug has not been seen and fixed previously: Calls to `memcmp` with two literals are rare, and code that both does that and depends on the magnitude of the result or uses characters having high bits set is rarer.

(I reported the bug to Apple.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's a bug in your particular implementation of `memcmp`.

I tried your program on my OSX/Darwin system and got a positive number.  So my system doesn't have the bug.

Oddly, though, the behavior on my system differs depending on whether I use `clang` or `gcc`.  I thought they used the same libraries, but `clang` gives 128 and `gcc` gives 1.  (Perhaps `memcmp` is implemented as a compiler builtin on one or the other.)

Also, incidentally, `man memcmp` on my system doesn't have the "This behavior is not required by C" sentence.

Comment: That sentence is in the `memcmp()` man page, not `strcmp()`. I have it on my High Sierra system.

Comment: @Barmar Yipes!  My inadvertent typo made an already-confusing situation even more confusing.  I meant `man memcmp`, which doesn't have the sentence on my system (10.9.5),  either.

Comment: What does the footer say? Mine says `BSD                              June 4, 1993                              BSD`

Comment: It may be dependent on your version of XCode, that's where library man pages come from on MacOS.

Comment: My footer is identical to yours.  The sentence I'm talking about is "This behavior is not required by C and portable code should only depend on the sign of the returned value."  Does yours actually have that?  Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: Yes, my text is identical to what's in the question.

Comment: @Barmar Not that it really matters, but: I finally found the source.  I think the date in the footer is meaningless; it probably comes from the man macro package.  The source is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/share/man/man3/memcmp.3`, mtime 1428272219, sum 53473.  Also the same, but s/10.9.sdk/10.10.sdk/.

Comment: Mine is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/share/man/man3/memcmp.3` mtime 1516569195 (Jan 21 2018)

Comment: Surprisingly, this answer is incorrect! `memcmp` on macOS is correct. The compiler is wrong! It incorrectly processes calls to `memcmp` when both arguments are literals. Which explains why this has not been observed and reported previously; calls to `memcmp` in which both arguments are literals and the code uses characters with high bits set or depends on the magnitude of the result are rare. I drafted a new answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug in the manual. It's describing `strcmp()`, which stops comparing when it reaches a zero byte in one of the strings, since that's the string terminator; the longer string will then be considered greater (`"foobar"` is greater than `"foo"`). But `memcmp()` is for comparing arbitrary memory regions, not strings, so zero bytes are not treated specially.

However, this doesn't explain why `memcmp()` is returning `-1`. It should be comparing `'\200'` and `'\0'`, and returning a positive value. It seems like the Darwin `memcmp()` is comparing them as `signed char` rather than as `unsigned char`, so `'\200'` is `-128` rather than `128`. If the first string is anything from `"\200"` to `"\377"` it returns this incorrect result.

When I try your code on Linux I get `1` rather than `-1`. So this seems like a bug in the Darwin library. And also a bug in the man page, since it says they're compared as `unsigned char`.

I tried this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    printf("memcmp: %i\n", memcmp("\200", "\0", 1));
    printf("bcmp: %i\n", bcmp("\200", "\0", 1));
    printf("strcmp: %i\n", strcmp("\200", "\0"));
    return (0);
}
```

On Mac OS High Sierra it prints:

```
memcmp: -1
bcmp: 128
strcmp: 128
```

on Debian Linux I get:

```
memcmp: 1
bcmp: 1
strcmp: 1
```

The mention of zero-length strings in the man page is also incorrect. `"\0abc"` and `"\0def"` are both zero-length strings, because strings logically end at the null byte. But they compare different with `memcmp()`

```
printf("memcmp: %i\n", memcmp("\0abc", "\0def", 4));
printf("bcmp: %i\n", bcmp("\0abc", "\0def", 4));
printf("strcmp: %i\n", strcmp("\0abc", "\0def"));
```

prints:

```
memcmp: -1
bcmp: -3
strcmp: 0
```

Comment: The quote in the question doesn't seem to say anything about stopping at a `\0`, so where does the comparison with `strcmp()` come from? As far as I can see, the manual just uses `\0` as an example value, and mentions zero-length strings, since you could pass `memcmp()` a length of zero.

Comment: `"\0abc"` and `"\0def"` are both zero-length strings, but they should be different with `memcmp()`.

Comment: Well, that just seems a nitpickety way of saying the manual shouldn't talk about "string length", but the value passed to the function as the length. There's still no mention of stopping at a `\0`, which would seem to be an important feature of `strcmp()`.

Comment: Right, it shouldn't mention strings at all. It's also wrong when it says that it returns the difference between the first differing bytes. In my tests it always returns either `-1`, `0`, or `128`. Notice that `bcmp()` returns `-3` in my last example.

Comment: This answer misconstrues the meaning of “string” when discussing the result of `memcmp("\0abc", "\0def", 4)`. Although common parlance when discussing C is to use “string” to mean a null-terminated sequence of `char`, this meaning of the word is not dictated by the C standard. C 2011 [N1570] tells us `string.h` declares facilities for “manipulating arrays of character type” and “Various methods are used for determining the lengths of the arrays.” As used in computer science, “string” means a sequence of characters or, more generally, a sequence of items from a set.

Comment: Additionally, the man pages document functions (and other things) for general use, not just for C, and should not be read as constrained by the C standard. Indeed, many were first written before the C standard existed and cannot be expected to use the same terminology and conventions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil C strings have *always* referred to null-terminated sequences of char, that was not an innovation of the standards committee. That's why there are separate `strXXX` and `memXXX` functions.

Comment: @Bamar: As I wrote, that use of “string” is an unofficial meaning not dictated by the C standard. It may be used commonly by many people, but it is neither universal nor mandated. By interpreting the `memcmp` man page to be using “string” in that way, you are making a mistake. The `memcmp` man page correctly uses “string” with its general computer-science meaning.

Comment: I've been programming for 40 years, and I can't recall any C literature using the word in any other way than that unofficial meaning.

Comment: @Barmar: The `memcmp` man page is not C literature. It is Unix literature. It documents a routine that is part of Unix. Some C implementations piggyback on Unix to provide the same function, but C’s documentation for that is in the C standard. The man page defines the Unix function using its own terminology, and the C standard defines the function using C’s terminology.

Comment: It's Unix literature about a C function. C and Unix were developed together, they share lots of terminology.

Comment: @Bamar: They share lots. They differ in some. You have found a difference.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for any use of "string" that doesn't mean "null-terminated sequence of characters"? I've never heard of it being used formally or informally in any other way.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If I may butt in: I think Barmar's as much of an expert as you; you don't need to lecture him.  I think the legitimate difference you two have discovered is one of opinion, between yours and his.

Comment: We have two competing situations. One is that the `man` page uses “string” in the null-terminated sense, and (a) incorrectly describes `strcmp` instead of `memcmp`, (b) incorrectly specifies the result of comparing zero-length strings when `memcmp` is passed a non-zero length, and (c) has not been fixed after considerable time has passed. The other is that the `man` page uses “string” in the general computer science meaning and is correct. I see no reason for preferring the former interpretation.

Comment: The man page is wrong in many ways. Why do you want to interpret its use of "string" so generously? If they meant "when n is zero" they could have just said that.

Comment: @Bamar: [Wikipedia on “string” in computer science.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science))

Comment: @Barmar: I interpret it thusly because (a) when so interpreted, the page is correct, (b) it is a definition used in computer science, and (c) I have used other programming languages, textbooks, and communications where it has that meaning.

Comment: @Bamar: [Turns out it is a bug in the compiler.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50548264/298225) The actual `memcmp` routine produces the correct result, as documented.